# Trying to understand usage of Item a bit better?

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick, qquickitem

I'm going through a tutorial on QML and they've started using Item as the base for every component they create, after using `Rectangle` for the first portion of the tutorial.

The thing is, `color` doesn't seem to be a valid property on Item. I don't understand why.

Then, I looked at a bunch of example component definitions on-line from a variety of places, and they seem to all use `Item` as the top-level class and then immediately after, `Rectangle`. What's the point of wrapping a `Rectangle` in `Item`? Why not just use `Rectangle` as the top-level class?

Comment: You should think of `Item` as a base class for all the other components. All other QtQuick types (except windows at the moment) derive from Item (QQuickItem on C++ side). It doesn't have `color`, as it doesn't implement any shape. Sort of unmoulded matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of Item as of a non-visual Rectangle that is a bit easier and faster for system to paint as, well, there is nothing to paint. It doesn't really make much difference of whether you use Item or Rectangle as a top level element - it is just a good programming practice not to use more resources than you need.

You will appreciate Item more if you start creating your own non-visual elements at some point.

Comment: That last sentence cinched it.

Answer (score 4):

From the Qt documentation :

> For creating components (or displaying a simple scene), there are
>   different elements that could be used as the top-level component. To
>   display a simple scene, a Rectangle as the top-level component may
>   suffice. Rectangle, FocusScope, Component, QtObject, Item, are some of
>   the commonly used elements as the top-level component.

So you can have any element as the top level component.

Note that QML visual items like `Rectangle`, `TextEdit`, `Image`, ... inherit from `Item` . `Item` is useful for grouping items together. You can use `Item` to create  an invisible container to hold other components.  So it facilitates handling children and processing properties such as focus width and height.

I think having `Item` as the top level component is like having a template for making arbitrary QML components. When your custom component is loaded into another QML scene, the component will retain the top-level component's properties. So you can have a general and non-visual element like `Item` as the top level item and expose arbitrary properties.